# Is it faster to search in a dictionary than in a list?

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary, time-complexity

I'm new to Python and I've noticed that there are 2 ways to search for a key in a dictionary:

```
d={1: 'a', 2: 'b',...}
if 1 in d: ...
```

or

```
if 1 in d.keys():
```

I thought they were the same but since I've had to search in a dictionary of 100 000 elements, I've seen that the second way takes too much time. I've looked for and read that this is so because `d.keys()` returns a list then the time complexity to search an element is O(n) but the complexity of search in a dictionary is O(1). Is that true?

Comment: See [the wiki entry on this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for more information.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for the information :) I didn't know it!

Comment: No problem - I just Googled "python dictionary list o(n)". Since you saw real-world results yourself, and you mentioned that you already did research online, I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for here other than "yes, you did come to the right conclusion." And you did. :)

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `dict.keys()` returns a view object and it also supports O(1) lookups.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  No, I wanted a reliable source of information and you gave it

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Ok, thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Most dictionaries are implemented as a hash-map. so you have O(1) for the access. that is much faster then O(n) for a list.

Why does it take just O(1)?
Because a hash map hashes every key, and put it in the resulting bucket. If you search for a key, it will hash your input and look if there is a value. if there is a value it returns it, otherwise you get informed that there is no entry. just as a quick glance...

if you are interested in stuff like this, you should have a look in "introduction to algorithms" by cormen

Comment: It's close to O(1). It diverges slightly when there are key collisions.

Comment: that is right, but as far as I know that would be represented by a constant value. O(1*c) would be also right, but you can drop constant values, so it should be O(1)

Comment: I don't think it's a constant. It's dependent on the key space and number of items. But not really important to the question at hand.

Comment: but the idea of a hash-map is to use a hash-algorithm with low collision prediction... so you it should be a very small value... but right it is not constant, but I guess is it no problem to ignore it...